# Import text file as list in python

Tags: python

I want to import a text file into my Python file and add each name in each line as a string to a list through a for loop.
This is my text file:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I tried this:

```
text_file = open("01.txt", "r")
list1 = text_file.readlines()
list=[]
for name in list1:
    list.append(name)
print (list)
```

But the output is this:

```
['A\n', 'B\n', 'C\n', 'D']
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```py
text_file = open("01.txt", "r")
list1 = text_file.read().splitlines()
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that involves fewer changes, is to change from

```
list.append(name)
```

to

```
list.append(name.strip())
```